# Compare values of multiple columns based on column identifier

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes.

The first one looks like this (number of channel will vary depending on the Type) This dataframe stores the type of device and the value for each channel.

```
+-----+----------+----------+
| Type|X_ChannelA|Y_ChannelB|
+-----+----------+----------+
|TypeA|        11|        20|
+-----+----------+----------+
```

The second dataframe is imported from an csv and is generated by me.

Right now I have this format (Can be changed to anything needed)

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| Type|X_ChannelA_min|X_ChannelA_max|Y_ChannelB_min|Y_ChannelB_max|
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|TypeA|             8|            12|             9|            13|
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Now I want to compare the actual Channel values to the min and max ones and create a new column with _status which contains a one if the value is in between min and max and a zero if it exceeds either min or max.

Wanted result for this examples

```
+-----+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Type|X_ChannelA|Y_ChannelB|X_ChannelA_status|Y_ChannelB_status|
+-----+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|TypeA|        11|        20|                1|                0|
+-----+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Code is here:

```
    val df_orig = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      ("TypeA", 11, 20)
    )).toDF("Type", "X_ChannelA", "Y_ChannelB")

    val df_def = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      ("TypeA", 8, 12, 9, 13)
    )).toDF("Type", "X_ChannelA_min", "X_ChannelA_max", "Y_ChannelB_min", "Y_ChannelB_max")
```

I have tried a few different things already without success.

Like creating columns by getting a string array of all channels and then creating the columns with

```
val pattern = """[XYZP]_Channel.*"""
val fieldNames = df_orig.schema.fieldNames.filter(_.matches(pattern))
fieldNames.foreach(x => df.withColumn(s"${x}_status", <compare logic comes here>)
```

My next idea was to join df_orig with df_def and then add channel_value, channel_min, channel_max with concat_ws into a single column, compare the values with the compare logic and write the result into the column

```
+-----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------+-------------+...
| Type|X_ChannelA|Y_ChannelB|X_ChannelA_array|Y_ChannelB_array|X_ChannelA_st|
+-----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------+-------------+...
|TypeA|        11|        20|     [11, 8, 12]|     [20, 9, 13]|            1|
+-----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------+-------------+...
```

If there is a simpler solution it would be nice to get a push into the right direction.

Edit: If my description was unclear basically what I am looking for is:
what i am looking for is

```
foreach channel in channellist (
    ds.withColumn("<channel>_status", when($"<channel>" < $"<channel>_min" || $"<channel>" > $"<channel>_max"), 1).otherwise 0)
)
```

Edit: I found a solution which is:

```
val df_joined = df_orig.join(df_def, Seq("Type"))
val pattern = """[XYZP]_Channel.*"""
val fieldNames = df_orig.schema.fieldNames.filter(_.matches(pattern))
val df_newnew = df_joined.select(col("*") +: (fieldNames.map(c => when(col(c) <= col(c+"_min") || col(c) >= col(c+"_max"), 1).otherwise(0).as(c+"_status))): _*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` is the way to go. And you have to utilize `when` function appropriately as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df_orig.join(df_def, Seq("Type"), "left")
  .withColumn("X_ChannelA_status", when(col("X_ChannelA") >= col("X_ChannelA_min") && col("X_ChannelA") <= col("X_ChannelA_max"), 1).otherwise(0))
  .withColumn("Y_ChannelB_status", when(col("Y_ChannelB") >= col("Y_ChannelB_min") && col("Y_ChannelB") <= col("Y_ChannelB_max"), 1).otherwise(0))
  .select("Type", "X_ChannelA", "Y_ChannelB", "X_ChannelA_status", "Y_ChannelB_status")
```

You should get your desired output as

```
+-----+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|Type |X_ChannelA|Y_ChannelB|X_ChannelA_status|Y_ChannelB_status|
+-----+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|TypeA|11        |20        |1                |0                |
+-----+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**Updated**

If you have more columns in your *channel dataframe* and if you don't want to hard code all the columns as mentioned above then you can benefit from `foldLeft` (a powerful function in scala)

But before that you will have to decide the columns you want to iterate (i.e. the channels)

```
val df_orig_Columns = df_orig.columns
val columnsToIterate = df_orig_Columns.toSet - "Type"
```

Then after you `join` them, use `foldLeft` to generalize the above `withColumn` process

```
val joinedDF = df_orig.join(df_def, Seq("Type"), "left")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finalDF = columnsToIterate.foldLeft(joinedDF){(tempDF, colName) => tempDF.withColumn(colName+"_status", when(col(colName) >= col(colName+"_min") && col(colName) <= col(colName+"_max"), 1).otherwise(0))}
```

Finally you `select` the necessary columns as

```
val finalDFcolumns = df_orig_Columns ++ columnsToIterate.map(_+"_status")
finalDF.select(finalDFcolumns.map(col): _*)
```

I guess thats it. Hope its more than helpful

Comment: This works but sadly not for my case.. I can't hardcode all the withColumn. There are devicetypes with 130+ channels.  
My problem is to make column generation dynamic.

Comment: do you have min and max for all the column channels then?

Comment: I want to compare every channel where where min and max is present.
I found a way to get a list for all channels. basically what i want is:
foreach channel in channellist (
    ds.withColumn("<channel>_status", when($"<channel>" < $"<channel>_min" || $"<channel>" > $"<channel>_max"), 1).otherwise 0)
)

Comment: @user2811630, I have updated the answer :) please have a look

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I am going to test your code with my original dataset. I also figured out a working solution. If you wannt to have a look at it I edited it into the original question.

Comment: I never heard about foldleft before. This look interesting. So many possibilities :) Thanks